# QML Video doesn't work robust with UDP streaming

Tags: qt, video, ffmpeg, qml

I am using QT/QML to write a player for raspberry-pi. I need to know what is the best practice of using Video QML element for a robust streaming play.

My QML code is like below,

```
Video {
    id: streaming_video
    width : parent.width
    height : parent.height
    autoPlay: false;
    opacity: 0.0
    fillMode : Image.Stretch
    muted : false
}

function switch_udpstream_on() {
    streaming_video.opacity = 1.0;
    streaming_video.source = "udp://localhost:7777";
    streaming_video.play();
}

function switch_udpstream_off() {
    streaming_video.opacity = 0.0;
    streaming_video.stop();
}
```

Once I started streaming sender like below,

```
ffmpeg -re -i 519183632_4.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f mpegts udp://rpi-ip:7777
```

It shows the load of logs rpi player back end and start infinitely printing,

WARNING: No decoded frame to show at all. Let' render black.

even though I stop sender, player is not stopping printing the above.

If I use `ffplay` instead, it works fine.

Comment: Are you using this project maybe https://github.com/carlonluca? How do you start ffplay?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) the ffplay command is,
ffplay udp:localhost:7777
No I am not using that project :( Is there someplace they use udp streaming in QML video?

Comment: Where did you get that Qt build? What multimedia backend are you using?

Comment: I am very new and I am not sure what you're exactly asking :( I wrote the QML file and that has been loaded in the main method. No specific backend is used. Is there specific way of doing what I want in that project?

Comment: Insufficient information sorry. Can't help you. Where did you download you raspberry image from then?

Comment: Used this guide to create and mount the rpi image https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi_Beginners_Guide

Comment: Anyways this question is not specific to the rpi, I am compiling this to Desktop version also, still the app seems not that robust like ffplay :(

Comment: I doubt you can resolve it just by asking here. For the similar case I have written my own QML plug-in in C++. Too much work to describe in the reply for the question. Try to use the search context "QAbstractVideoSurface plug-in".